# How to get IP address of docker container in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, docker, jenkins-plugins, boot2docker, dockerfile

Is there any command to get the docker container's ip address from jenkins, after a new container is created? Basically, once docker creates the container, I want to connect that container to another container and need to do further deployment on it.

Comment: See: https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/

Answer (score 3):

Use docker inspect command.

$ sudo docker inspect -f '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' containerID

This command can be run as execute shell command from jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

For getting IP from jenkins for a running container there is two ways.
1. if your job is running in master you can use docker-build-step plugin. in this case jenkins will use docker engine of master machine only.

2. if docker is running on slave machine and job is restricted to that slave machine. we need to use execute shell in jenkins and run following command

   docker inspect $(docker ps |grep {{image id}}|cut -d ' ' -f 1)|grep IPAddress|cut -d '"' -f 4

this will give ip for the container running with that specific image id.
If there is more than one container running with same image id, it will generate ip from latest container.